# Find specific value in dataframe cells and print row header with matching columns for that value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a Python starter using Python 3.7.0 so apologies for the blunders with my code below.
I have imported an excel spreadsheet into a dataframe which shows in Jupyter as below.

```
    Title  Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4
0    A       P             O      P
1    B              P             O
2    C              P      P      P
3    D       P                    P
```

I am trying to find value `'P'` for each row and print the Title label followed by all the `column` headers with that found value.

The desired output is better illustrated for what I am trying to achieve below:

Output:

```
Title A: Name1, Name4
Title B: Name2
Title C: Name2, Name3, Name4
Title D: Name1, Name4
```

This is my code so far:

```
#Sample data to recreate pd in this forum
data = {'Title':  ['A', 'B','C', 'D'],
        'Name1': ['P', '', '','P'],
        'Name2': ['', 'P','P',''],
        'Name3': ['O', '','P',''],
        'Name4': ['P', 'O','P','P'],
        }  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df_so = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Title', 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4'])
```

Neither of the codeblocks below return an output

First attempt:

```
for (index_label,row_series) in df_so.iterrows():
    if row_series == 'P':
        print(index_label + ':' + row_series.values)
```

Second attempt:

```
my_data = df_so.to_numpy()
for idrow, row in enumerate(my_data):
    for idcol, col in enumerate(row):
        if not pd.isnull(col):
            print("Title:" +str(idrow) + ":" + str(idcol) )
```

Can someone please suggest a way to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `Title` to index, compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and create new column with [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication, last add [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df_so.set_index('Title')
df2 = df1.eq('P').dot(df1.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').reset_index(name='new')
print (df2)
  Title                new
0     A        Name1,Name4
1     B              Name2
2     C  Name2,Name3,Name4
3     D        Name1,Name4
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot !